# Is this double integral improper?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the double integral of $f(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$ over the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,3)$, and $(5,3)$, which is written as
$$
\int_0^3\int_{\frac{2}{3}y}^{\frac{5}{3}y}\frac{y^2}{x^2}\,dx\,dy.
$$
This integral can be easily evaluated through conventional means, yielding
$$
=\int_0^3\frac{-y^2}{x}\bigg|_{\frac{2}{3}y}^{\frac{5}{3}y}\,dy=\int_0^3\frac{9}{10}y\,dy=\frac{9}{20}y^2\bigg|_0^3=\frac{81}{20}.
$$
One can observe that $f$ is undefined at $(0,0)$.  Furthermore, the discontinuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is nonremovable, as
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)\text{ does not exist.}
$$
And yet, the fact that $f$ is "bad" at $(0,0)$ never seems to to show up anywhere in our previous calculation.  (This brings to mind $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$, which is improper, but "takes care of itself" enough that a blind calculation never notices.)  I still have a few questions:

1. Is this integration, in fact, improper? $f$ is bounded on the triangle described above, as the largest value it can acquire is on the boundary line $y=\frac{3}{2}x$: $f(x,\frac{3}{2}x)=\frac{9}{4}$.
2. Does the nonexistence of the limit of $f$ (and $f$ itself, for that matter) at $(0,0)$ cause any problems for us?  Or can we simply say "$(0,0)$ is a set of measure zero, so no problems"?
3. Can we run into problems if our "bad" set of domain values is measure zero but dimension 1?  (Unlike our current example, which is measure zero and dimension 0.)
4. In general, can we ignore any bad behavior on a measure zero set as long as our function is bounded?

Comment: Compute the inner integral and you’ll find that the outer is not improper as you suggest.As for the others: 2. maybe if you want to swap order of integration, but as is, no. 3. Yes. 4. No, not in a Riemann sense anyway